# AUTOHOTKEY If left mouse pressed.. loop..something

Tags: loops, send, autohotkey, mouseclick-event

This is my current code:

```
LButton::

Send {sc013}
Sleep 10
Send {sc021}
Sleep 10
Return


RButton::

Send {sc014}
Sleep 10
Send {sc021}
Sleep 10
Return
```

And all what I need is... isnsted of when left mouse/right mouse button clicked do something.....

 I need that when left/right mouse button **HOLDED** loop letter "**F**".

 Thnk you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use [`GetKeyState()`](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm) and a [`While-loop`](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/While.htm). So while `Rbutton` is pressed, send `F`.

```
Rbutton::
    while (GetKeyState("Rbutton", "P")) {
        Send, F
    }
return
```